# javascript subnamespaces are not initializing

Tags: javascript, namespaces

I want my javascript file to look like:

```
    var A= A|| {};
    var A.B= A.B|| {};
    var A.B.C= A.B.C || {};

    A.B.C.myFunc = function ()
    {};

    A.B.C.myFunc.prototype  = {
    f1: function(){},
    f2: function(){}
    }
```

where A is the main namespace, B is one of its sub namespaces and C is one of the namespaces of the B, but at the moment this structure is not able to initiate the sub namespaces. Any suggestions why?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You must not declare the subNamespaces with `var`:

```
var A= A|| {};
A.B= A.B|| {};
A.B.C= A.B.C || {};
```

Otherwise the javascript interpreter will trigger an error ( you cannot declare a variable with a point : `var A.B` is wrong and A is already an object ).

Comment: Dear god... Thank you so much for this!!! I was so focused on the logic in my methods...

Comment: You're welcome. You should use the console (F12) on your navigator to debug errors. (you should also validate the answer if it suits you).